# How check in android application that phone are going to shutdown (power off)?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, reboot, power-off

Is any method which i can call and it return to me information that phone actual going to shutdown (power off).
I know that is intent ACTION_SHUTDOWN but I have to get information about shutting down the phone form anther source. The best is directly form system. Maybe checking of same files in /proc or in /sys fs.

Comment: Which means, tick the answer that you find best.

Answer (score 1):

Use BraodcastReceiver, extend it and override `onReceive`.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

When you want to use it:

```
activity.registerReceiver(receiver, shutDownIntent);
```